# How to increment by one when key is pressed?

Tags: lua, love2d

Using love2d, I can not increment a variable by one when something happens.

For example, when the space bar is pressed I would like `x` to increment by only one, and not change again until the space bar is pressed again. Currently, while the space bar is down it keeps adding one at a very quick speed, and continues until I release the space bar.

Here is an example of the code as it is now.

```
function love.load()
    x = 0
end

function love.update(dt)
    if love.keyboard.isDown(" ") then
        x = x +1
    end
end

function love.draw()
    love.graphics.print("space pressed for "..x.." times.",100,100)
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve better results using the [`love.keypressed`](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.keypressed) event handler.

```
function love.load ()
    x = 0
end

function love.keypressed (key)
   if key == ' ' then
      x = x + 1
   end
end

function love.draw ()
    love.graphics.print ("space pressed for "..x.." times.", 100, 100)
end
```

If you have repeated keys on, via [`love.keyboard.setKeyRepeat`](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.keyboard.setKeyRepeat):

```
love.keyboard.setKeyRepeat (true)

function love.load ()
    x = 0
end

function love.keypressed (key, rep)
   if key == ' ' and not rep then
      x = x + 1
   end
end

function love.draw ()
    love.graphics.print ("space pressed for "..x.." times.", 100, 100)
end
```